# Struts2 + Tomcat MIME type for CSV uploads

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, struts2, mime-types

I am using Struts2 file upload ( http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/file-upload.html ) to upload a CSV or Excel file which I will parse.

The MIME type is being set as `application/vnd.ms-excel` for both file types and I want to make the CSVs `text/csv`. This is so I can just check the MIME type and call the corresponding parser.

I've tried adding the following to Tomcat's web.xml but it has had no effect:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>csv</extension>
    <mime-type>text/csv</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just putting it out there maybe not a universal solution but you should be able to create a file upload action of the form (I think the mime type is determined by the application server so is outside of struts.)

```
<package name="upload" extends="struts-default"> 
  <action name="*.*" class="someClass">
    <param name="filePrefix">{1}</param>
    <param name="fileExtension">{2}</param>
  <action name="*.*" class="someClass">
</package>
```

***Not tested*** then you could call it with http://address_and_port/context_root/upload/myFile.jpg

Not as encompassing as the mime type but if you're only doing a handful of files it'll work and perhaps its a trick worth remembering (you can even have an action with slashes and parse out the values between them as parameters).

PS: I don't know if escaping is required for dots...